# Angular ng-if multiple conditions not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

This is a relatively simple question but I cannot figure out why this isn't working.

So I have ng-if statement in HTML where I check condition if its not true. as in:

```
<div class="new-asset" data-ng-if="$root.questionData.question_type_id != '1' || $root.questionData.question_type_id != '8'">
```

But for some reason this does not work. I also tried:

```
<div class="new-asset" data-ng-if="($root.questionData.question_type_id != '1' || $root.questionData.question_type_id != '8')">
```

Which has no affect whatsoever... I was reading up and trying to find a solution, someone suggested placing the condition in controller, which would also have performance increase (not 100% sure if it would), as in:

```
$scope.addNewAssetIf = $root.questionData.question_type_id != '1' || $root.questionData.question_type_id != '8';
```

and then referencing it in html as:

```
<div class="new-asset" data-ng-if="addNewAssetIf">
```

But I cannot use this approach due to asynchronous loading, and dependencies. I need to make this work somehow, I get no errors or anything, even though the question_type_id is 1 I still get .net-asset div shown. If I remove OR statement and only have 1 condition it works:

```
<div class="new-asset" data-ng-if="$root.questionData.question_type_id != '1' || $root.questionData.question_type_id != '8'">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that the `question_type_id != '1' || question_type_id != '8'` always returns `true`

Comment: did you check that it returns a number as a string and not as an actual number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm ignoring everything angular related and trying to understand the basic logic behind the condition. If the ID == 1 won't it satisfy the second condition which asks it to be different from 8? And isn't that true for cases where the ID is 8?

In other words, don't you need && instead of ||?

This should really be a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Legend...! :) I knew this was a simple thing... I think I might have gotten my own logic little wrong here haha :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using a function:

```
$scope.addNewAssetIf = function() {
  return $root.questionData.question_type_id != '1' || $root.questionData.question_type_id != '8';
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is questionData is being loaded after addNewAssetIf() is run. I cannot change this either due to other dependancies. I know we dont live in ideal world, but ideally I need HTML version to work :/

Comment: had you not used a function, the value of addNewAssetIf would be static. using a function creates a dynamic return which refreshes on each digest cycle in angular. this means the value will be refreshed once your async method completes and the value of questionData is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using `$rootScope` instead of `$root` and include `$rootScope` as a dependency in your controller? The issue could just be that the variable is not in scope. You could also assign this to your `$scope` and then reference it directly in your template

Basically, the idea is to try and see if the values are bound to your template fine. You could even try and

`{{$root.questionData.question_type_id}}</div>`

To verify this, and then if not, start by addressing the root cause.